# Sqoop Incremental Load With Epoch Timestamp

Tags: sqoop, hadoop2, epoch

Using Sqoop incremental tool needs last modified date to be provided in `--last-value` in format similar to `2016-09-05 06:04:27.0`. The problem in this case in the source `MySQL` databases, update_date data is stored as Epoch timestamp( `1550218178`).

With the following sqoop command

```
sqoop import --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://192.18.2.5:3306/iprocure_ip --table depot --username usernamehere --password-file /user/admin/.password --check-column update_date --incremental lastmodified --last-value '1550218178' --target-dir /user/admin/notexist --merge-key "depot_id"
```

Thows an error stating that the date in epoch timestamp provided is not a timestamp

```
19/03/06 12:57:31 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Column type is neither timestamp nor date!
19/03/06 12:57:31 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Column type is neither timestamp nor date!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Column type is neither timestamp nor date!
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.datetimeToQueryString(ConnManager.java:788)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.initIncrementalConstraints(ImportTool.java:350)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:526)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:656)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:186)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:249)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:258)
```

How can one fetch incremental data with sqoop using Epoch timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is clearly saying that there is type mismatch and Sqoop is expecting date or timestamp but your --last-value format is int.

If you read the sqoop documentation, is says...

> Incremental imports are performed by comparing the values in a check column against a reference value for the most recent import. For example, if the --incremental append argument was specified, along with --check-column id and --last-value 100, all rows with id > 100 will be imported

Since Sqoop is internally Java and it must match java.sql.Data types. Recheck the DDL and adapt the sqoop import command.

Comment: As stated in the question, the source database stores `update_date` in `INT` type (Epoch timestamp), how can i make sqoop work with Epoch timestamp?